# On 5% of the days, John’s computer does not work...

Tags: probability, statistics

I need help in the following question. I know that I have to solve for 
$P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(A) P(B\mid A) P(C\mid A \cap B)$.
But I'm not sure how to get $P(B\mid A)$ and $P(C\mid A \cap B)$. Any suggestions?

On 5% of the days, John’s computer does not work. If the computer does not work, then he turns on the television, and independently of the computer, on 20% of the days he finds nothing interesting on television. If he finds nothing interesting on television, he calls his wife at work. Independently of television programming and the computer, on 35% of all occasions she does not pick up the phone. In that case, John goes out. On what percentage of days does John go out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On 5% of the days, John’s computer does not work.

$\mathsf P(A)=0.05$

> If the computer does not work, then he turns on the television, and *independently* of the computer, on 20% of the days he finds nothing interesting on television.

$\mathsf P(B\mid A)=\mathsf P(B)=0.20$

> If he finds nothing interesting on television, he calls his wife at work. *Independently* of television programming and the computer, on 35% of all occasions she does not pick up the phone.

$\mathsf P(C\mid A\cap B)=\mathsf P(C)=0.35$

> In that case, John goes out. On what percentage of days does John go out?

$\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap C)=\mathsf P(A)\mathsf P(B)\mathsf P(C)$

Long story short: You have Independence.